# Multiple rows with 2 condition in the same column MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

How to select multiple rows with 2 condition in the same column MySQL

students' table:

```
id  name
1   Jhon
2   Anne
3   Charles
4   Bob
```

lesson_contract's table:

```
id  lesson_code student_id
1   L1          1
2   L2          1
3   L1          2
4   L1          3
5   L2          3
6   L2          4
```

So i want to get student that take both lesson_code L1 and L2. So the result should be Jhon and Charles

Comment: Have you attempted anything to satisfy this requirement? If so please show us

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by joining into the `lesson_contract` table twice, once for each lesson code:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name FROM students s
INNER JOIN lesson_contract l1
    ON s.id = l1.student_id AND l1.lesson_code = 'L1'
INNER JOIN lesson_contract l2
    ON s.id = l2.student_id AND l2.lesson_code = 'L2'
```

Inner joins will filter the results, so you'll only get rows where both join conditions were met.

Answer (score 0):

You must join the tables, `group by name` and put the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select s.name
from student s inner join lesson_contract l
on l.student_id = s.id
where l.lesson_code in ('L1', 'L2')
group by s.name
having count(distinct l.lesson_code) = 2
```

You may remove `distinct` if there is no case for a student to take the same lesson twice.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cU9rqSuMijrZMUaf89LMgj/0).
Results:

```
| name    |
| ------- |
| Charles |
| John    |
```